# While Compling jquery mobile code,Script tag is not working in Eclipse Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

When i compile a `jquery mobile` code,the script tag is not working,Did i missed any code?Suggest me a answer,My code has been displayed below..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>WELCOME TO MY HOMEAPP</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Hi Frndz..</p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>USER LOGIN</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your app permission access internet. 
In config.xml file:

```
    <access origin="*" />
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```